# File too big when converting pdf to jpg using ImageMagick/Ghostscript

Tags: bash, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to have an identical output to what Adobe Acrobat does with File>>Save As>>Image>>JPEG. But whenever I use ImageMagick's `convert` it takes much longer and the resulting file is 2-3x bigger. I set the density option to `-density 686` because that was the density of Acrobat's output according to the following:

[image]

Here is the result of convert (filename changed to Bitter_Creek.jpg), not sure why it says aspect ratio and the dimensions will still differ even when setting the size option to `-size 14859x18388`

[image]

Using the `ls -l` command to describe the resulting JPGs I get this:

(top file is result of ImageMagick's `convert` and the bottom file is result of Acrobat's Save As:

[image]

I would like to know which options to use to get an identical output.

Comment: You never said what your exact ImageMagick command line was? That might be a start to see what is happening? File size and dimensions depend upon the density supplied to the reading of the PDF and to any resize done afterwards. As well as to the jpg quality you assign for the file size.

Answer (score 0):

Filesize of a jpeg image depends on quality setting.  The default setting of Acrobat is "Medium" whose quality value is considerably low (62), whereas ImageMagick's convert is defaulted to higher value.
If you expect the equivalent result, add `-quality 62` option to convert, although picture quality will be accordingly degraded.

Comment: ImageMagick quality default is whatever is in the input or 92, if no quality is set. So in this case it is probably using 92, which will make your jpg larger in file size.